# PHP cookies doesn't save on HTTPS

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, session-cookies

This code works perfect on my localhost but when I try to use it on a secure (https) server, the cookie is never set.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(0);

            if (isset($_COOKIE["count"]))
            {
                //cheak user refreshes

                         $cookie = (int)++$_SESSION['count'];
                         setcookie('count', $cookie, time() + 900, '/');
                         $PopExitUrl="https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&good=1';



            }
            else 
            {
                   setcookie('count', 1, time() + 900, '/');
                   $PopExitUrl="https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&bad=1';


            }

     ?>
```

- this is the first lines of code of that page
- this page has redirect code on the bottom that redirect the page to itself (refresh)

Comment: Just wondering, but how do you know it isn't set? Did you try `var_dump($_COOKIE)`?

Comment: yes and it isn't set...